# Creating test individuals for all classes of an ontology

Tags: sparql, owl

I'd like to test an OWL ontology. As it is big, I'd like to automatically create named individuals as members of each class, one per class, having the name of the class, appended with "1". As far as I know there is no iteration mechanism in SPARQL update. But there might be other ways to achieve it. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The "iteration" is in SPARQL matching.  The way to think of it is that the engine produces a result set containing each match in the `WHERE` clause.  It then executes the `SELECT`/`CONSTRUCT`/`DELETE`/`INSERT`/... clause for each match.  Hence SPARQL is more of a declarative language, and trying to think of it in procedural terms doesn't fit the paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be that difficult:

```sql
SELECT ?cls ?ind {
  ?cls a owl:Class .
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR(?cls), "1")) AS ?ind)
}
```

This query generates an individual for each class. You can put this SELECT query in the WHERE part of an SPARQL Update query (untested):

```sql
INSERT {
  ?ind a ?cls .
} WHERE { 
   ?cls a <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class>
    BIND(iri(concat(str(?cls), "1")) AS ?ind)
}
```